# Can't run a example by Doop - Framework for Java Pointer Analysis

Tags: java

I am trying to using Doop framework. I am following this link: https://bitbucket.org/yanniss/doop

I downloaded the code and compiled it successfully. but when I am trying to Running Doop by the following command

```
$ DOOP_HOME>./bin/doop -a context-insensitive -j ./lib/asm-debug-all-4.1.jar
```

in my case, it  is :

```
./doop -a context-insensitive -j ../lib/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar
```

But, unfortunately, I got an error.

```
vuquangvinh@vuquangvinh-VPCEA24FM:~/tutorial/DoopFramework/code/doop/bin$ ./doop -a context-insensitive -j ../lib/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar 
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/vuquangvinh/tutorial/DoopFramework/code/doop/lib/ivy-2.3.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
The EXTERNALS directory is invalid: null
```

I have no idea what is happening. I have tried, but this framework seems to be not popular. Anyone can help me!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/yanniss/doop) the tool expects several environment variables `DOOP_HOME`, `DOOP_OUT`, `DOOP_HOME` and `DOOP_EXTERNALS` to be set and it simply complains that `DOOP_EXTERNALS` is not set.

Instead of setting the environment variable you can also pass the externals directory via command line option `--externals <the directory>`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I config the DOOP_EXTERNALS variable and it works.